# Wakeup lock is not working in android mobile app

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, wakelock, sleep-mode

My wakeup lock is not working in android. I have used below code:-

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
               "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire(IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES+1000);
```

In the manifest file I have also mentioned:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Please provide more details. What are you trying to achieve ? An app or an activity within that app that keeps the screen on??

Comment: No there is login to backend. I am trying to keep cpu awake so that after 10 mins of inactivity app should logoff the backend. But timer does not run for 10 mins after inactivity